# angular2 formBuilder group causes nesting of params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, strong-parameters

I have the following formBuilder in angular2:

```
constructor(
  private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = formBuilder.group({
      id: [],
      title: ['', Validators.required],
      dates: formBuilder.group({
        start_date: ['', Validators.required],
        end_date: ['', Validators.required]
      }, {validator: this.checkDates})
    });
}
```

`dates` is in a separate group, this is for validation purposes. onSubmit calls this service method:

```
update(academicTerm: AcademicTerm): Observable<AcademicTerm> {
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  return this.http
    .patch(this.endpointUrl + academicTerm.id, JSON.stringify(academicTerm), {headers})
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

When I check the backend (Rails5 API server) I can see this param set:

> Parameters: {"id"=>"3", "title"=>"Term Title", "dates"=>{"start_date"=>"2016-11-27", "end_date"=>"2016-12-01"}, "academic_term"=>{"id"=>"3", "title"=>"Term CL"}}

Note in the `academic_term` hash that `start_date` and `end_date` are not present.

On the Rails side of things I have strong params set up like this:

```
def academic_term_params
  params.require(:academic_term).permit(:id, :title, :start_date, :end_date)
end
```

I have tried setting the nested `dates` object in strong params:

```
def academic_term_params
  params.require(:academic_term).permit(:id, :title, :dates => [:start_date, :end_date])
end
```

Which has no affect (dates is not an associated attribute?).  So while I can update title I cannot update the dates.

Is there a way to flatten the params sent from angular to be something like this:

> Parameters: {"id"=>"3", "title"=>"Term Title", "start_date"=>"2016-11-27", "end_date"=>"2016-12-01"}

Or is there a way to fix it on the Rails side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flatten the object before sending the request to the server.

```
update(academicTerm: AcademicTerm): Observable<AcademicTerm> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    academicTerm['start_date'] = academicTerm.dates.start_date;
    academicTerm['end_date'] = academicTerm.dates.end_date;
    // delete academicTerm.dates; // optional

    return this.http
        .patch(this.endpointUrl + academicTerm.id, JSON.stringify(academicTerm), {headers})
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: `academicTerm['start_date'] = academicTerm['dates'].start_date;` and `academicTerm['end_date'] = academicTerm['dates'].end_date;` did the trick, thanks